# How to prevent CSS Grid blowout so that text-overflow ellipsis will work

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am having some issues with CSS Grid "blow out" which is causing my text property `text-overflow: ellipsis` to not work.

I have seen many posts on this, and tried many things, but just don't understand what I have wrong. I can reproduce in a simple example.

In my case, I am using a third part component, where I want to put my UI inside one of it's elements.

For example, below the element `third-party-container` is the third part component, and my UI is contained in `my-container`m where I wish to completely fill the `third-party-container`

HTML

```
<div id='third-party-container'>
  <div id='my-container'>
    <div id='s1'>S1</div>
    <div id='s2'>S2</div>
    <div id='s3'>aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #third-party-container {
        height: 40px;
        width: 140px;
        background: orange;
    }

    #my-container {
        background: yellow;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display:grid;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: left;
        grid-template-columns: min-content 13px minmax(0, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        column-gap: 2px;
        white-space: nowrap;            
    }

    #s1 {
        background: red;  
         grid-row: 1;
         justify-items: left;
         grid-column: 1;          
         align-items: stretch;   
    }

    #s2{
        background: green;
        grid-row: 1;   
        overflow: hidden;               
        grid-column: 2;   
    }

    #s3 {  
        background: pink;
        grid-row: 1;      
        justify-items: left;
        display: grid;
        align-items: center;
        grid-column: 3;                                         
        min-width: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;   
    }
```

Also available [at this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zJpytN7I4LgxjVNh)

So in `my-container` I have a single row, and 3 columns. The first two columns have quite small widths. The first columns may vary slightly, but will always be quite small. The 2nd is just fixed.

The third column `s3` (coloured `pink`) is the one that may sometimes have longer text than can fit in the containers. However, this is what I see in the above example...

[image]

When I look at this in dev tools, I can see the s3 is "blowing out", ie not being contained within its container.

[image]

I had got around this before by using the `minmax(0, 1fr)` but it is not working here.

The outer container has a fixed width, and my-container is 100% of this.

What am I doing wrong and how I can get this to work?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the use of `display:grid` on `#s3`. Remove it and also add `width:100%`

```css
#third-party-container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 140px;
  background: orange;
}

#my-container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: left;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 13px minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  column-gap: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#s1 {
  background: red;
}

#s2 {
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#s3 {
  background: pink;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='third-party-container'>
  <div id='my-container'>
    <div id='s1'>S1</div>
    <div id='s2'>S2</div>
    <div id='s3'>aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow that was quick and thank you so much! I always have display:grid on any divs displaying text as in the past I thought I had to do this to center the text vertically. But I did the above (in my case) and the text still seems ok. Strange how display:grid would do that (e.g my-container is contained and it has display:grid), yet that was the problem.